# Как сделать скриншот и отправить на сервер?

Tags: php, c#, сервер

Мне надо сделать скриншот с экрана и после отправить на сервер.

Со скриншотом я разобрался, но как его теперь передать на сервер?

Comment: Это тоже самое, что спросить "Как передать сообщение Васе из соседнего города?", согласитесь, странно это спрашивать у незнакомых людей, верно? Ибо вы можете приехать к нему и сами сказать, отправить почтой, отправить курьером, передать через знакомых, передать азбукой морзе, сказать по телефону, отправить электронно. Как видите, способов уйма и только вы знаете какой из них более оптимальный для вас. Конкретно в вашем вопросе вы совершенно нечего не указали, а ведь отправить на сервер также, можно кучей способами. Так от куда нам знать, как работает ваш сервер и как с ним взаимодействовать?

Comment: а что означает тег [php] в вашем вопросе?

Comment: @Borislav А причем тут ajax?

Comment: @ГеннадийП `то как его передать на сервер ?` - это вопрос, `Ajax — подход к построению интерактивных пользовательских интерфейсов веб-приложений, заключающийся в «фоновом» обмене данными браузера с веб-сервером.`- это определение ajax-а. Еще вопросы?

Comment: @Borislav Причем тут браузер с веб-приложением, если автор хочет программой на C# делать скриншот экрана и отправлять на сервер?

Comment: @ГеннадийП А при чем тут приложение? Вы не можете фронт на шарпе писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю это вам поможет, однако, лучше уточнять, что именно вы пишите, фронт на шарпе или же аппликейшн. 
https://metanit.com/sharp/net/2.3.php

```
private static async Task PostRequestAsync()
{
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5374/Home/PostData");
     request.Method = "POST"; // для отправки используется метод Post

     // данные для отправки
     string data = "sName=Hello world!";

     // преобразуем данные в массив байтов
     byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

     // устанавливаем тип содержимого - параметр ContentType
     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

     // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Length запроса - свойство ContentLength
     request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

     //записываем данные в поток запроса
     using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
     {
         dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
     }

     WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
     using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
     }

     response.Close();
     Console.WriteLine("Запрос выполнен...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Загрузка файлов на сервер через php

```
php 

<?php
$uploads_dir = './files'; //Directory to save the file that comes from client application.
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
?>

c#

  System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();

            Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");

            byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://localhost/moysayt/upload.php", "POST", @"C:\autobuy.txt");

            string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
            MessageBox.Show(s);
```